# Group Policy software installation failing with error %%14

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, msi

I have created a GPO configured to "assign" `\\<AD DNS domain name>\NETLOGON\<file name>.msi` and verified that it's applying to the Windows 10 v1809 PC but the actual installation consistently fails.

RSoP reports the following:

```
20 June 2019 14:10:23

Software Installation failed due to the error listed below.
Not enough memory resources are available to complete this operation.
```

Event Viewer reports the following:

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy
Date:          20/06/2019 14:48:10
Event ID:      1085
Task Category: None
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      <PC FQDN>
Description:
Windows failed to apply the Software Installation settings. Software Installation settings might have its own log file. Please click on the "More information" link.
```

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Application Management Group Policy
Date:          20/06/2019 14:10:23
Event ID:      108
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      <PC FQDN>
Description:
Failed to apply changes to software installation settings. Software changes could not be applied. A previous log entry with details should exist. The error was: %%14
```

I have:

1. Found that the error `%%14` doesn't seem to be documented online, hence my main reason for posting this.
2. Verified that Group Policy is already configured as recommended for these scenarios (`Specify startup policy processing wait time` set to 60 seconds and `Always wait for the network at computer startup and logon` set to enabled).
3. Verified that the connection between the PC and DC is 1 Gbps
4. Found that manually running the MSI from NETLOGON on the PC works fine.

**Update: 2019/06/26 09:29**

I have:

5. Found that this very GPO applies successfully on 2 other Windows 10 v1809 PCs.
6. Tried deploying 7-Zip's MSI to the affected PC but it fails with the same errors.
7. Found some events that suggested slow DNS initialisation so temporarily removed Webroot SecureAnywhere's DNS Protection Agent but found that doing so didn't make a difference.

**Update: 2019/06/26 14:08**

I have:

8. Enabled Windows Installer logging as per https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/223300/how-to-enable-windows-installer-logging but I couldn't find anything relevant in `%tmp%` or `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved by .OLD-ing the following registry keys and rebooting:

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\AppMgmt`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\History`
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\AppMgmt`
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\History`